# Hay how do you do a box around an equation in $\LaTeX$?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

I just don't know how to do it.

I have seen it in other posts, but I can't find them.

Comment: Poking you to accept one of the answers ;)

Comment: I hate having to choose between friends.

Comment: Thank you for choosing, next time you need to choose Matt over Peter :)

Comment: @jojeck , I need you to answer some questions about Royi and Overlord in the other thread.

Comment: See the [Math.SE MathJax FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/510296), community [answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22395/510296), for the full syntax for an outlined colored box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\fbox{ Like this for text.}$$

> \fbox{ Like this for text.}

or

$$\boxed{e^{j\pi} = -1}$$

> \boxed{e^{j\pi} = -1}

---

This sort-of works for colors:

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\color{black}{e^{j\pi} = -1}}}$$

> \color{red}{\boxed{\color{black}{e^{j\pi} = -1}}}

for an equation.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  Is there a way to specify the color of the box?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson That's an attempt...

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about either the `\color` or `\boxed` instructions.

Answer (score 1):

In Mathjax you can do something like this (which I used in [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/72991/4298)):

```
\bbox[#f8f1ea, 0.6em, border: 0.15em solid #fd8105]{a^2+b^2=c^2}
```

Looks like this:

$$\bbox[#f8f1ea, 0.6em, border: 0.15em solid #fd8105]{a^2+b^2=c^2}$$

You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/bbox.html).

Comment: thanks Matt.  do you know where I can find this documented?  I presume the first word somehow specifies the the color but what does the second word (`0.6em`) specify?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I added the doc-link at the end of my answer.